# .net 3.1 application running inside docker is failing to connect SQL server

Tags: entity-framework, docker, .net-core

I had one application running in .net core 2.2 and connecting to SQL server 2012. Now I have upgrade  my .net core application to 3.1 and also upgraded EF core. 
After up-gradation this application fail to connect, while running inside docker container. but if I run same application in window machine then it gets connected successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is issue with security in docker container. 
this can be resolve by updating  openssl.cnf inside docker

I have added following line in docker file

```
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Comment: If this resolved your issue, you should accept this an an answer.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: This did not work for me https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/222#issuecomment-605559779

Comment: @reggieboyYEAH Maybe you need to set minimum TLS protocol as well? From that same issue thread, check out the comment that has solved the problem for a lot of people: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/222#issuecomment-535941637